# Is there a way to reuse pre-existing Redis Subscribers

Tags: go, websocket, redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to reuse pre-existing Redis Subscribers to a certain channel I have in order to limit the number of connections I have with my redis cluster. I want to be able to store something like a Subscriber ID and be able to reuse this subscriber in the future so I don't have to create a new one. Is there a way to do this in Redis?

For those wondering I am creating websocket connections in Golang which are subscribing to Redis channels and I want to do my best to limit the number of connections to the Redis cluster.

Comment: I just realized I can store the pointer to the Subscriber returned